# SQL Server Hosting

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, hosting, web-hosting

I am looking for a SQL Server Hosting Provider that meets the below requirements:

- Using SQL Server 2008 Standard or Enterprise Edition (No EXPRESS)
- Allows directly connecting from SQL Management Studio
- Around $5 to $10 a month
- Don't need to store more than 100 MB

Answer (score 3):

Try http://www.webhost4life.com/hosting.asp, **Advance Plan**

- MSSQL 2008
- Management Studio support
- $10/mo
- 2000 MB storage

Answer (score 1):

I have Googled this for you but I am having trouble finding anything. I found one place willing to do it for $10 but that is on top of the cost of taking out hosting with them.

They built the express editions for people with lower requirements and unfortunately because of the SPLA licensing costs, I do not think you will find anywhere that can do standard or enterprise for that budget.

I also saw that Godaddy can do it for $5, and you get a 200MB SQL database which seems to be the cheapest, however I doubt you will have access to Management Studio and no idea what version it is.

Sorry I couldn't be more help but as I said, I do not think you are going to find a place.

That being said, go to http://www.webhostingtalk.com and go to the section where you can post your requirements and cross your fingers - you never know!